# How to launch existing packages after upgrading python3

Tags: python, homebrew, upgrade, pipenv, pythoninterpreter

I use macOs Sierra version 10.12.6 on my MacBook Air, and python 3.7 and pipenv, Today I ran `brew upgrade` and updated Xcode Command Line Tools from App store. After that I found out that the python is upgraded to 3.8 version.
My problem is that when I want to go in virtual environment writing `pipenv shell`, this message is shown:

> -bash: /usr/local/bin/pipenv: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

I had this problem for using my favorite python IDE, spyder, too, and reinstalled it by `pip3 install spyder` and then it was launched, but I'm afraid to reinstall pipenv because I have important projects kept in virtual environment made using pipenv.

I'd like to know what is the best solution for this situation?

Comment: This might sound a bit hacky to you, but it could work.  You could try adding a symbolic link with the old version's root directory name, pointing to the new version's root.  If the new one was installed in the same place, then I'm talking about `sudo ln -s /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.8 /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7`. - I can't think of any downside to giving this a shot.  The act of creating the link is certainly safe.

Comment: I did it but resulted in this message  `ln: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7: No such file or directory`

Comment: Sorry.  Looking again at the path, I think what I gave you wasn't right.  I'd have to see how your installs are laid out to know just what command you'd want to run.  If you understand the basic idea, I think it would work if you can figure out the details.

Comment: Thanks for your helps @Steve , the result for `which python3` was `/usr/local/bin/python3`, and There are python3.6, python3.7 and python3.8 folders, each containing only a folder named site-packages, including files and folders related to packages installed. I'd like to be able to use all packages installed before on python3.7. especially pipenv usually with the command `pipenv shell`.